# Сложности с исключающей выборкой в MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

Есть три таблицы:

**product**

| product_id | model | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | ghx | 100 | 20 |
| 32 | thx | 130 | 0 |
| 65 | r61 | 170 | 21 |
| 85 | bh8 | 120 | 20 |
| 95 | bh8 | 140 | 20 |

**product_description**

| product_id | name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | ваза | что-то есть |
| 32 | тумба | что-то есть |
| 65 | стол | что-то есть |
| 85 | стол | что-то есть |
| 95 | стол | что-то есть |

**product_analogs**

| product_id | analog_id |
| --- | --- |
| 65 | 85 |
| 65 | 95 |
| 85 | 65 |
| 85 | 95 |
| 95 | 65 |
| 95 | 85 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f11b509f68e482c98790e674df730b6f

Проблема с третьей таблицей, если без неё нужно выбрать товары, то пишу запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description pd 
ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
WHERE p.quantity > 0 
GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.price ASC
```

В итоге получаю выборку товаров с product_id: `25,85,95,65`

Но есть задача прикрутить к запросу третью таблицу (аналоги), с таким условием, чтобы в выборке исключить аналоги товаров (65,85,95 - это аналоги друг друга), то есть в итоге должен получиться результат выборки такой: `25,85`

То есть товары 95 и 65 исключаются, так как они указаны как аналоги для 85, а 85 взят потому что у него цена ниже чем у 65 и 95.

Просьба помочь кто знает как это сделать в запросе, каких-то вариантов у меня нет, не осиливаю.

Comment: *если без неё нужно выбрать товары, то пишу запрос* И что же в этом запросе делает LEFT JOIN? зачем он?

Comment: *То есть товары 95 и 65 исключаются, так как они указаны как аналоги для 85, а 85 взят потому что у него цена ниже чем у 65 и 95.* А если у двух аналогов одинаковая минимальная цена - какой выводить?

Comment: LEFT JOIN для того, чтобы сопоставить и получить в выдаче и поле `name` из `product_description`, я же выбираю SELECT *

Comment: Если цены одинаковые, то любой товар, но скорее всего я в рабочем варианте буду еще добавлять сортировку по `pd.name`

Comment: Какая ТОЧНО версия MySQL?

Comment: Сервера разные, на одном 10.3.29, а на другом 5.5.65

Comment: 10.3.29 - надо понимать, MariaDB? на ней - запросто, с рекурсивным CTE. На 5.5.65 - только в формате хранимой процедуры.

Comment: Ну я в этом не совсем понимаю, тут как говориться, наши полномочия всё. Может формат таблицы с аналогами поменять? В принципе могу как угодно сменить если это поможет сделать легкий и универсальный запрос.

Comment: *Может формат таблицы с аналогами поменять?* Для того, чтобы задача решалась запросом в MySQL 5.5, таблица аналогов должна содержать два поля: идентификатор продукта и номер группы аналогов. Т.е. в твоём случае там будет три записи - (65,1), (85,1) и (95,1). Но такую структуру поддерживать геморройно... впрочем, она позволяет проводить контроль целостности и непротиворечивости данных (ошибка в записи в нынешней структуре способна объединить две группы аналогов в одну, и хрен ты это поймаешь, а предлагаемая структура делает это элементарно, ибо требует уникальности продукта).

Comment: Но если двигаться в этом направлении, то таблица аналогов вообще не нужна, а поле группы следует расположить прямо в таблице продуктов. С другой стороны, если Б аналог А, а В аналог Б, то, наверное, это не означает, что В есть аналог А... и даже что А есть аналог Б.

Comment: В принципе тогда можно убрать таблицу аналогов, а товары одной группы пометить полем `angroup` в таблице `product`. Но всё равно не могу разобраться как тогда сделать запрос чтобы И лишних аналогов не было И исключение аналогов было с учетом условий `WHERE p.quantity > 0 и т.д.,` коих может быть несколько, например `WHERE p.quantity > 0 AND p.price > 100 и т.д. и т.д.`

Comment: *исключение аналогов было с учетом условий* Только аналогов? или и оригиналов тоже? с другой стороны - ну какая разница-то, сколько условий и каких? всё равно 2 копии таблицы, связанные по полю группы аналогов, а накладывать условия что на одну копию, что на две.